# cant boot using bootable usb. stuck at manufacturer logo

Tags: software-installation

[**when use ubuntu safe graphics this shows**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/132Kb.jpg)

I had Pop OS before this, which showed some problem while upgrading to 21.10 beacause it also used to get stuck at Lenovo logo. Someone suggested try installing Windows before installing back Linux so I installed windows which currently i have. now  when trying to come back to Ubuntu but getting stuck every time. something to do with kernel. I checked memtest86. also tried to forced format old Linux recovery partition from windows disk management.then I downloaded Ubuntu 21.10 ISO file from Ubuntu site and installed it on USB using Rufus software. I verified that USB is valid installation on other computer and it works fine.I am new to this so please give steps to resolve it. PC Think pad e14 AMD ryzen 5 gen3.

I am not trying to dual boot. wants clean install.

Comment: Please use a newer release to start with something.

Comment: Are you sure that the USB contains valid bootable media? How did you create it? Did you verify the download? Did you verify the flash? Does it pass integrity checks? Are you trying to install Ubuntu?  What version of Ubuntu are you trying to boot?  Please edit your question with the answer to all of these questions and also include any other essential details you left out.

Comment: @Nmath yes i tried same USB installation stick on other computer and it works.

Comment: Hello. I have seen this info before always coming from the same guy. There is no need to install Windows in order to be able to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to install ubuntu,

- Download the stable version of ubuntu https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=20.04.4&architecture=amd64
- Then using rufus make a bootable USB.
- select a partition scheme as GPT (I think it's appropriate for you)
- Now after a boot Ubuntu should run smoothly. Just follow the steps and have fun.

Comment: Hello. This is missing steps when did the ISO get verified?

Comment: Yes, I just mentioned the main step which @Ash242 required.

Comment: Niranjan - This doesn't seem like an answer at all.. OP already knows how to make a bootable USB. OP is asking for a solution and why it is not working